# Stopping disabled elements from changing page size?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search bar with a toggle button above it. When I click the toggle button, it gradually changes the opacity. It works great, but it looks a bit clunky, because when I disable it (thus hiding the element), it changes the size of my page. Is there an alternative way of disabling and hiding the element?

Javascript:

```js
function ToggleSearchBar() {
  var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
  var display = getComputedStyle(searchbar).display;
  if (display == "none") {
    searchbar.style.opacity = 0;
    searchbar.style.display = "block";
    var i = 1;

    function IncreaseOpacity() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        searchbar.style.opacity = i * .1;
        i++;
        if (i <= 10) {
          IncreaseOpacity();
        }
      }, 30)
    }
    IncreaseOpacity();
  } else {
    var v = 10;

    function DecreaseOpacity() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        searchbar.style.opacity = v * .1;
        v--;
        if (v >= 0) {
          DecreaseOpacity();
        } else {
          searchbar.style.display = "none";
        }
      }, 30)
    }
    DecreaseOpacity();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="search-button">
  <p onclick="ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
  <form id="SearchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="        Your query here">
  </form>
</div>
```

I tried tinkering with the *disabled* property, but that didn't work out. If you have any suggestions, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Which element do you want to disable?

Comment: The form element. You can see the changes being made to it in the js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your `display = "none"` to `visibility = "hidden"`. This should do the trick.

```js
function ToggleSearchBar() {
  var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
  var display = getComputedStyle(searchbar).display;
  if (display == "none") {
    searchbar.style.opacity = 0;
    searchbar.style.display = "block";
    var i = 1;

    function IncreaseOpacity() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        searchbar.style.opacity = i * .1;
        i++;
        if (i <= 10) {
          IncreaseOpacity();
        }
      }, 30)
    }
    IncreaseOpacity();
  } else {
    var v = 10;

    function DecreaseOpacity() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        searchbar.style.opacity = v * .1;
        v--;
        if (v >= 0) {
          DecreaseOpacity();
        } else {
          searchbar.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      }, 30)
    }
    DecreaseOpacity();
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search-button">
  <p onclick="ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
  <form id="SearchBar">
    <input type="text" placeholder="        Your query here">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that worked just fine after I changed the rest of the respective properties. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how your css style it ! But to prevent page from resizing you can set fixed property for your parent element . As a example , I give fixed height to parent `.search-button` class , you can do your own by refrencing it

```js
function ToggleSearchBar() {
            var searchbar = document.getElementById("SearchBar");
            var display = getComputedStyle(searchbar).display;
            if (display == "none") {
                searchbar.style.opacity = 0;
                searchbar.style.display = "block";
                var i = 1;
                function IncreaseOpacity() {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        searchbar.style.opacity = i * .1;
                        i++;
                        if (i <= 10) {
                            IncreaseOpacity();
                        }
                    }, 30) 
                }
                IncreaseOpacity();
            } else {
                var v = 10;
                function DecreaseOpacity() {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        searchbar.style.opacity = v * .1;
                        v--;
                        if (v >= 0) {
                            DecreaseOpacity();
                        } else {
                            searchbar.style.display = "none";
                        }
                    }, 30)
                }
                DecreaseOpacity();
            }
        }
```

```css
.search-button {
background :#eee;
padding:10px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "search-button">
        <p onclick = "ToggleSearchBar()">Search</p>
        <form id = "SearchBar">
            <input type = "text" placeholder = "        Your query here">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there an alternative way of disabling and hiding the element?

- You can use the "visibility: hidden" property instead of "display: none". The element is hidden (but still takes up space)

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: Was working on my code based on your suggestion when holydragon posted. Same idea though. Thanks a lot man